# I want to find all the pairs in the following Binary Search Tree for which sum is 12

Tags: binary-search-tree

[image]

**Approach**

I am maintaining two stacks, one for inorder traversal and the other for reverse inorder traversal, but can't seem to figure out a way to print both 2 10, and 5 7. How should I go about this ? I want to have a space complexity of O(height) and time complexity of O(nodes). I have seen articles on leetcode, geeksforgeeks etc. but am not able to get hold of this example

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: If it were working, would you be asking the question? On this site, you're supposed to include some (pseudo)code in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example